# Automapper not mapping from a source containing a single nullable boolean field

Tags: c#, automapper

I'm seeing some very strange behaviour in Automapper when mapping from a object with a single `Nullable<bool>` property. I currently have it set up like this:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public bool? IsAThing { get; set; }
}

public class MyEntity
{
    public bool? IsAThing { get; set; }

    public bool? HasAnotherThing { get; set; }

    public string AnotherThing { get; set; }

    // Lots of other fields
}
```

with the following mapping profile (with a similar reverse mapping):

```
CreateMap<MyViewModel, MyEntity>()
    .ForMember(x => x.IsAThing, opt => opt.MapFrom(y => y.IsAThing))
    .ForAllOtherMembers(opt => opt.Ignore());
```

However if I try to do the following:

```
var config = new AutoMapperConfig().Configure();
var mapper = config.CreateMapper();

var source = new MyViewModel { IsAThing = true };
var dest = new MyEntity();

mapper.Map(source, dest);
```

`dest.IsAThing` is null. The mapping profile is the only place where `MyViewModel` is declared as a mapping source. Strangely, if I declare the class

```
public class AnotherThingViewModel
{
    public bool? HasAnotherThing { get; set; }
    public string AnotherThing { get; set; }
}
```

And do the following test:

```
var source = new AnotherThingViewModel { HasAnotherThing = true };
var dest = new MyEntity();
mapper.Map(source, dest);
```

`dest.HasAnotherThing` is `true` as expected!

Obviously I have no idea what's going on here so has anyone seen anything like this before, or knows of any bugs in Automapper that might cause this?

Comment: Can't reproduce this with provided code and last (6.1.1) version of automapper nuget package (that is - `dest.IsAThing` is true and not null).

Comment: Please edit your question to include a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we can see/test the source code you have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out, I had `CreateMap<MyViewModel, MyEntity>().ForAllMembers(opt => opt.Ignore())` elsewhere in my mapping configuration!